# If possible optimisation a+=b*c with carry?

Tags: c, optimization, multiplication

Main code fragment in GMP/MPIR multiplicaiton is mpn_mul_basecase:

```
mp_limb_t addmul_1(mp_ptr rp, mp_srcptr up, mp_size_t n, mp_limb_t vl)
{
    mp_limb_t ul, cl, hpl, lpl, rl;
    cl = 0;
    do
    {
        ul = *up++;
        umul_ppmm(hpl, lpl, ul, vl);
        lpl += cl;
        cl = (lpl < cl) + hpl;
        rl = *rp;
        lpl = rl + lpl;
        cl += lpl < rl;
        *rp++ = lpl;
    } while (--n != 0);
    return cl;
}
```

where for VC++

```
#    define umul_ppmm(xh, xl, m0, m1)       \
     do  {                                  \
           xl = _umul128( (m0), (m1), &xh); \
         } while (0)
```

and for GCC having 128 bit type:

```
         do  {                                  \
        mp_limb_double_t w = (mp_limb_double_t)x * y; \
        r_lo = (mp_limb_t)w;                             \
        r_hi = (mp_limb_t)(w >> GMP_LIMB_BITS);                     \
    } while (0)
```

But optimalized asm code for specified processor (my processor is Haswell) is twice faster: https://github.com/wbhart/mpir/blob/master/mpn/x86_64w/haswell/addmul_1.asm
Why? Because this loop is expanded or uses mulx instead of mul? One I am notices that source memory must be efficiently indexed by RSI and destination memory by RDI. But I don't know how efficient indexing memory cell which must be read+added+writing. Is possible optimized it with plain C? One I see is _addcarry_u64 from  but is also slow.

Comment: On the one hand, I see you struggle with the difference between C and C++. On the other hand, I see sophisticated numerical code. This probably explains why I can't understand what you are asking. I don't think there's a realistic answer possible here.

Comment: Previously assembler tests give me near twice speedup but latest only 28% and independent of optimized assembler version. Now it is not possible such good assembler results.